# Moving Magento site removed settings

Tags: magento

I am trying to set up a copy of a Magento site for development use. I have copied the code from the server and grabbed a copy of the database.

I setup Apache, PHP, redis, MySQL, php-curl.
I added the DB user with all privileges and imported the DB.

When I load the Magento site up it loads with the default theme. Going to System > Configuration > Design shows it has defaulted all the options and they are not what they are on the live site.

Where is this configuration stored that it wasn't copied with the rest of the data? Products are all there etc, it just seems to be system configuration like cache enabling and theme etc.

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Clearing the cache and enabling changes nothing. On a new copy cache is all disabled as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came down to the DB export script which wasn't including data for the `core_config_data` table. After doing a manual export myself the site had all its options.